# Ardunio HM-10 BLE Scanner development

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm using an Ardunio uno with a HM-10 module. I am trying to scan for all beacons around me and then store the beacon names

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

String inputTXT;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX  


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  mySerial.begin(9600);

  //setup
  mySerial.write("AT");
  delay(100);
  mySerial.write("AT+ROLE1"); // Master mode
  delay(100);
  mySerial.write("AT+IMME1"); //wait for a connection command before connecting 
  delay(100);
  mySerial.write("AT+RESET");
  delay(50);

}

void loop() {  

  delay(3000);


  mySerial.write("AT+DISI?");

  if (mySerial.available()) {
    inputTXT = mySerial.readString();

    Serial.println(inputTXT);

    inputTXT = ""; 
  }
}
```

I get this output repeated at every loop

```
OK+DISISOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:00000OK+DISISOK+DISCEOK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:38F9D379C9E5:-065OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4CAA0DE091B7:-066OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:72363EC2C661:-084OK+DISC:4C000C0E:008D37DBECB6B76115D006C9B3FA1005:1B1C1E7B5B:76854777DBD7:-072OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:38F55DEDE396:-079OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:4D023B8ED54D:-083OK+DISC:00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:6B5DB3EB2
```

So i now want to save the 12 digit string before the final colon of each iteration such as '4CAA0DE091B7' can someone show me or advice me how i would go about doing that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no regular expression for Arduino, so you need to do it manually.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

String inputTXT;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
    //setup
    Serial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.write("AT");
    delay(100);
    mySerial.write("AT+ROLE1"); // Master mode
    delay(100);
    mySerial.write("AT+IMME1"); //wait for a connection command before connecting
    delay(100);
    mySerial.write("AT+RESET");
    delay(50);
}

void loop()
{

    delay(3000);
    mySerial.write("AT+DISI?");
    if (mySerial.available())
    {
        inputTXT = mySerial.readString();
        int pos = 0;
        String result = "";
        const String regx = "00000000:00000000000000000000000000000000:0000000000:";
        const int regx_len = regx.length();
        while ((pos = inputTXT.indexOf(regx, pos)) != -1)
        {
            // substring from <starting point> to >starting point + 12>
            result = inputTXT.substring(pos + regx_len, pos + regx_len + 12);
            Serial.println(result);
            // move starter point to end of last result
            pos = pos + regx_len + 12;
        }
    }
}
```